# Merge multiple JSON in one output

Tags: json, mongodb, etl, talend

I'm working on a BI project when I need to combine two JSON in one output to insert in MongoDB.

Screen of job:

[image: Screenshot]

The first JSON is like that :

```
{
   "idCommand": 1
   "name": "Maurice"
}
```

The second JSON is like that :

```
{
   "products": [

       {
          "name": "Banana"
       },
       {
          "name": "Orange"
       },
    ]
}
```

The final JSON that we want :

```
{
   "idCommand": 1
   "name": "Maurice",
   "products": [

       {
          "name": "Banana"
       },
       {
          "name": "Orange"
       },
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is no join, this is a simple concatenation. Are you sure there will always be a record in the first and second source which can be connected? I would first concat the two fields and then use `tWriteJSONField`. The only problem is that there would be an outer and an inner loop (first do this for all first JSON, then first JSON #2...) and not a 1:1 loop as far as I know.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, in my oracle database I have two tables : commands and commands_product. commands contains the header of command and commands_product contains the product associated to commands. I want to make only one json with nested array.

Comment: "*contains the product associated*" -  there is no visible association. As far as I understand this result, it is pure concidence that the records can be concatenated. But if those are just two tables, you should think about `join`ing the tables in Oracle, `select` the result and write JSON fields. Should be a lot easier. Again, depends if the tables are joinable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working ! I used INNER JOIN. I have an other problem with MongoDB, when I formatted my JSON with "tWriteJSONField" and sent it in tMongoDBOutput the result is like that : { "_id": ".....", "output": "{"idCommand": 1, ....}"} instead of : {"_id": "....", "idCommand": 1, ....}

Comment: I created an answer out of the comment. Please consider accepting it if it has helped you. For the MongoDB issue, please create another question, then we can have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Created out of a comment:

"*contains the product associated*" - there is no visible association. As far as I understand this result, it is pure concidence that the records can be concatenated. But if those are just two tables, you should think about `join`ing the tables in Oracle, `select` the result and write JSON fields. Should be a lot easier. Again, depends if the tables are joinable.